# Can i pass an variable TSender in a MessagingCenter?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, messagingcenter

I'm trying to do this with this examples:

```
public void Method1(object someClassAsTSender, object parameter)
{
    //i think parametertype = parameter...
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<someClassAsTSender, parametertype> (this, "messageKey", (message, args) =>
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            //await do;
        });
    }
    );
}
```

or

```
public void Method2(object someClassAsTSender, object parameter)
{
        //i think parametertype = parameter...
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<someClassAsTSender, parametertype> (this, "messageKey", (message, args) =>
        {
            //do;
        }
    );
}
```

I tryied to use GetType().Name, typeof(), but no have idea how i solve this.
 It's just a doubth, because to MVVM i considerate an use of Framework more interestant.

If it is not correct to use MessagingCenter in this way, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Subscribe<TSender,TArgs> (object subscriber, string message, Action<TSender,TArgs> callback, TSender source = null) where TSender : class;
```

`TArgs` is the type of the objects that are used as message arguments for the message，but you could not use `typeof` or `GetType` to set it.you could set it to `object` like :

```
public void Method1(object someClassAsTSender, object parameter)
 {
   //i think parametertype = parameter...
   MessagingCenter.Subscribe<someClassAsTSender, object> (this, "messageKey", (message, args) =>
    {
       //convert the type (e.g  string data = args as string)
       Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
          //await do;
        });
    }
   );
 }
```